# Salary of researcher in Germany

Tags: germany

There were many strikes in Germany recently, but there is no news about salary increases for researcher TVL employees. The next due date is on 30.09.23.

Is there any information about the salary increase for researchers? Will there be a similar hike?

Comment: The negotiations will start at the end of October.

Comment: @Maeher, thanks, is there any website or source to follow it?

Comment: All information will be posted here https://oeffentlicher-dienst.info/tv-l/allg/. There are also websites that cover the negotiations. But all information will probably be in German.

Comment: The increase will be limited to a percentage which is not decisve for choosing a career as a researcher?! More decisive is the general level of salary, which can be found on the webpage mentioned by pgunnink

Comment: @pgunnink thanks for sharing the link, currently there is no information.

Comment: @Heinrich exactly, Researchers are always less paid workers but several pros and cons. But in the current situation, a significant hike is necessary.